# how to submit a login form with enter key in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2, enter

I am using Sencha Touch. I would like to login with pressing ENTER key in my key board.Can any one please know the answer please help.

Here is my code.

```
Ext.define('App.form.LoginForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'loginform',
    id: 'loginform',
    config: {
        items: [{
            html: '<br><div style="text-align:center;"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-5x icon-fill"></div>'
        },{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                id: 'username_fld',
                name: 'username_fld',
                required: true
            }, {
                xtype: 'passwordfield',
                id: 'password_fld',
                name: 'password_fld',
                placeHolder: 'Password',
                required: true
            }]
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            name: 'login_btn',
            itemId: 'logInButton',
            text: 'Log In',
            cls: 'x-form-fieldset'
        }]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         {  
            xtype: 'passwordfield',
            id: 'password_fld',
            name: 'password_fld',
            placeHolder: 'Password',
            required: true,
            listeners: {
                painted: function (field, e) {
                    document.addEventListener("keydown", myFunction, false);
                }
            }              
          }





 function myFunction(evt)  {  
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode == 13) { // charcode 13 for "entry" keyboard
        evt.preventDefault();
        var myApp = me.getApplication().getController('App');
        myApp.login()
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `keyup` event of the passwordfield, like this:-

```
refs: {
     password: 'passwordfield[name="password_fld"]'
},
control: {
  password : {
                keyup: function(field, e){
                    if(e.event.keyCode === 13) {
                        console.log('Do login'); 
                       // Your login code goes here
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but not satisfying the if condition on pressing the enter button.Getting the keycode in password field....So couldnt able to write the login code....

Comment: So what are you getting in the keycode. It was working in my project.

Comment: able to get keycodes on password field except the enter key...showing 65 on clicking 'a'...

Comment: You should put your solution in your question also so that others facing this problem will get help.